# xbee network communication topology question (need advise)

Tags: xbee, node-xbee

i have 3 Xbee s1 module, and want make mash topology network with Bidirectional communication.

The system I'm trying to make is:
about xbee module x1, x2, x3, (x1 is end device)

> 1 - x1 sends a message to x2, and x2 responds.
>
> 2 - when x1 receive a message, x1 sends a message to x3.
>
> 3 - when x3 receive a message, it sends respond to x1.

From what I've looked for, xbee didn't seem to be able to communicate between end devices in mash form.

Please advise me if it is possible to make, and what part of xbee should I study for it.

thanks...

Comment: Consider newer XBee hardware.  I believe the S1 just uses 802.15.4, but S2 and later implement mesh networking on top of 802.15.4.  Digi has a proprietary mesh protocol (DigiMesh) and also supports Zigbee.  Note that the mesh networking is automatic, and you won't know it's in use -- modules will select the best path to deliver the message and doing so happens transparently.  The "hops" won't provide any indication over the serial port that they're relaying messages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming-related question.